which tests must be passed in the HLK test to obtain the WHQL release signature?
I have developed a WFP network driver and need to pass the Windows Hardware Lab Kit (HLK) testing to get the WHQL release signature. I followed the steps in the Windows HLK Getting Started, but I'm unsure about how to select the minimal test set that can help me obtain a WHQL release signature. Should I pass all selectable tests or just load the corresponding playlist version and then pass the selectable tests? If neither of these is correct, please let me know how I can select the minimal test set.
